# WPF on Windows 2000

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, windows-2000

Are there some tricks to get WPF apps running on Windows 2000 (copying some system dll's for example?). There shouldn't be a technical reason why its not possible.

Answer (score 4):

There is a strong technical reason why this won't work - Microsoft didn't support the required .NET frameworks.

.NET 4 (and 3.5) is [not supported on Windows 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  The latest .NET framework supported in .NET 2, which doesn't include WPF.